# Generalised Extreme Value function of the Kolmogorov–Smirnov (KS) test in R

Tags: r, testing, kolmogorov-smirnov

What is the abbreviation of the Generalised Extreme Value function of the Kolmogorov–Smirnov (KS) test in R. I am trying the following code but it is not working:

```
ks.test(data.frame,"gev")
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first parameter cannot be a data.frame. It has to be a numeric vector.

Just pass the cumulative distribution function:

```
x <- 1:10

library(SpatialExtremes)
ks.test(x, pgev, scale = 0.1, shape = 1)
#
#   One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#
#data:  x
#D = 0.9131, p-value = 4.911e-11
#alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```